# NSUserDefaults only seems to work on older iOSs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

When I run the following code on iOS4.2 the defaults are saved.
But when I run in 5.0 they get lost when the user closes out (entirely closes out the app).

What am I missing?  thx

```
- (void) setupSave:(UIButton*)btn
{
    //save IP and Port
    strTcpIpAddress = [tvTcpIpAddress text];
    strTcpPort = [tvTcpPort text];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strTcpIpAddress forKey:@"tcpIpAddress"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strTcpPort forKey:@"tcpPort"];

    [tvTcpIpAddress resignFirstResponder];
    [tvTcpPort resignFirstResponder];
}
```

---

```
OnStartUp:
    //NSUserDefaults
    strTcpIpAddress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"tcpIpAdress"];
    strTcpPort = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"tcpPort"];

    //userName = NULL;
    if(strTcpIpAddress == NULL) strTcpIpAddress = @"10.0.0.7";
    if(strTcpPort == NULL) strTcpPort = @"4000";
```

Plist:

[image]

Comment: I think you're forgetting to synchronize your defaults after having set your objects to it.

Comment: call: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; after you do your setObject: calls.

Comment: Try using `objectForKey:` instead of `stringForKey:` when retrieving them.

Comment: Applied the fixes... nothing is saved or there is a problem when retrieving it.  Note that the user closes out entirely from the app so that nothing is running.

Comment: To confirm, that you do have a .plist file being registered with your app which contains the keys you have in the code above?

Comment: Appreciate your help... I added an image of the plist, not sure about adding the "keys" to it?

Comment: The defaults are automatically synchronised; there is rarely any need to do so yourself

Comment: How have you determined that the defaults "aren't working" on iOS 5?